# Django cannot find lightbox and bootstrap js file. Can someone solve this problem?

Tags: javascript, python, django, bootstrap-4

```
[11/Nov/2020 20:13:11] "GET /about HTTP/1.1" 200 3615
[11/Nov/2020 20:13:12] "GET /static/js/lighbox.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1677
[11/Nov/2020 20:13:12] "GET /static/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js.map HTTP/1.1" 404 1716
```

Here's the relevant part of my base.html for bootstrap:

```
{%  load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/all.css' %}">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.css' %}">
    <!-- Custom -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
    <!-- LightBox -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/lightbox.min.css' %}">


    <title>Real Estate</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Top Bar -->
    {%  include 'partials/_topbar.html' %}
    <!-- Navbar -->
    {%  include 'partials/_navbar.html' %}


    {% block content %} {% endblock %}
    

    
    <!-- Footer -->
    {%  include 'partials/_footer.html' %}
    

    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/lighbox.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/main.js' %} "></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Relevant code from settings.py

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'real_estate_btre/static')
]
```

And here's how my django project is laid out:

admin
db.sqlite3
project_name
manage.py
app_name
static - admin, css, js, img
template
base.html

I even ran the python mange.py runserver command as well, but I dont know why wont both the lightbox.js and bootstrap.js file load.

names of the files missing:

lighbox.min.js
bootstrap.bundle.min.js

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this in your urls.py?

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```